# Как в css сделать картинку сылкой, если в html картинки всплывают рандомно

Tags: html

как в css сделать картинку сылкой, если в html картинки всплывают рандомно, тоесть на каждую картинку отдельная ссылка

<script language="Javascript">
<!-- BEGIN
  var images = 3;
  var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(images-1))+1;

document.write('<div id="img_prehome'+whichImage+'">&nbsp;</div>');
  // END-->
</script>

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = [
  ['vk.com','http://cs424830.vk.me/v424830492/67ee/AQeO7bBxCco.jpg'],
  ['facebook.com','http://www.formulaworldshop.com/images/externe/facebook.jpg'],
  ['gmail.com','http://www.italia-news.it/media/contenuti/gmail.jpg']
];
i = i[(~~(Math.random()*i.length))];
document.write('<a href='+i[0]+'><img src='+i[1]+'></a>');
```

Заменяйте ссылки и адреса картинок на свои. И будет то, что обычно является ротатором баннеров. Пример работы на [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/upEVoKi/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: я на сайте захотел сделать чтобы при обновлении страницы в отдельном div-е были разные картинки, выводились рандомно. И чтобы нажимая на них можно было переходить на сайты, тоесть к конкретной картинки прикрепить конкретный сайт. Смены изображений я добился, ну а ссылки пока нет...(Извените если что не так написал, так как первый раз делаю сайт и паралельно самостоямельно учю html, css...)

Comment: отредактировал ответ с учётом вашего комментария. посмотрите пример работы и, если устраивает, замените свой код на мой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

<script>

```
    (function(){
        var images = 3;
        var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(images-1))+1;

        var href = ['#href1', '#href2', '#href3'];

        document.write('<a href="'+href[whichImage-1]+'"><div id="img_prehome'+whichImage+'">&nbsp;</div></a>');
    }())

</script>
```